# This logic level converter does not want to work

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage-level

I got this logic level converter to be able to use my lcd but I can't figure out how to get it to work, the problem is that the current is not passing through. This is the model: TXS0108E

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

[EDIT]

A few Combinations that I have tried:

[image]

[image]

And I tried to swap the voltages, same wiring as in the pictures but 3.3v instead of 5v and vice versa.

Comment: Could you tell what you tried? Did you pull the OE pin HIGH?

Comment: @Gerben okay, i will add a few photos with what i have tried

Comment: @Gerben I made the edit

Comment: Assuming your lines saying "3.3V" are connecting to a 3.3V power supply, your first picture is correct. VA => 3.3V, OE => 3.3V, VB => 5V and GND => GND.

Comment: @Majenko the 3.3V are connected to the lcd, the 5v is connected to the 5v Pin on the arduino.

Comment: Where is the 3.3V coming from?

Comment: The GNDs for the 3.3V and 5V are connected? I.e. not from isolated sources. If missing the connections you made for testing? For example, connect GND to A1 and read voltage on B1. Connect Vcc-A to A1, and read voltage at B1

Comment: @Majenko the 3.3V is connected to the lcd, i want to lower the voltage from the arduino (5v) to 3.3v

Comment: @Gerben well, the lcd is connected to GND on the arduino and the GND on the board is connected to the arduino aswell

Comment: @Gerben This isn't the first time, and I doubt it'll be the last time, where I have seen someone assume that a logic translator like this magically provides a regulated voltage out from VCCA...

Comment: @Majenko sorry about the silly mistake, i'm still learing. I am working on a project for physics.

Comment: @xM0nSt3r It's ok - as I said, I've seen it before. You're not the first, so don't beat yourself up about it :)  Maybe I should design and sell a 5V -> 3.3V logic level shifter with built-in regulator. And maybe a 3.3V -> 5V shifter with built-in 3.3V->5V boost regulator for users of 3.3V Arduinos...

Comment: @Majenko that would help avoid these questions :)) start working then :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TSX0108 doesn't magically provide you with a regulated voltage. You have to provide the voltage, the TSX0108 merely switches it.

As you can see from [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf), the basic wiring is:

[image]

In the circuit above the 1.8V connection is your 3.3V connection, and the 3.3V is your 5V connection.

**You must provide both the 3.3V and 5V power sources.**

Comment: and how do i provide 3.3 v from an lcd?

Comment: By connecting it to a 3.3V power source - such as the 3.3V pin of the Arduino.

Comment: so i provide 3.3v and 5v from the arduino, and then that regulates the data pins voltage?

Comment: Crudely speaking, yes. It's just a set of switches. A signal coming in through an A pin switches the voltage provided at B to the matching B pin. A signal coming in through a B pin switches the voltage provided at A to the matching A pin.